# Flash Builder components and loops

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm just getting the hang of coding, thanks in large part to this website... but I'm still noob and have another noob question.

I've created a simple calculator that my kids could use to work on their math skills, but I don't know how to loop it so that it will go 10 times. I understand the syntax of a for-else and an until loop, but not sure what to put in the loop itself.

The easiest way to do this (I think) might be to use a component or class (not sure which to use) and then call on it.

That said, here's my basic code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.components.FormItem;
        import spark.components.TextInput;

        public var n_1:Number = Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
        public var n_2:Number = Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
        public var ttl:Number 
        public var answer:Number
        public var n_right:int
        public var n_total:int = 1


        protected function check_bn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            n1.text = n_1.toString();
            n2.text = n_2.toString();
            ttl = Number(total.text);
            answer = n_1 + n_2
        if(ttl == answer) {
            yes_no_lbl.text = "YES, click NEXT!";
            n_right = n_right + 1


        } else { 
            yes_no_lbl.text = "NO, try again!";

        }

        }
        protected function next_bn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // reset variables
            n_1 = 0
            n_2 = 0
            ttl = 0 
    // use component here????

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>



<fx:Declarations>

    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>


<s:Form id="Calc" x="28" y="27">
    <s:FormItem label="1st #">
        <s:Label id="n1" text = "{n_1.toString()}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="2nd#">
        <s:Label id="n2" text = "{n_2.toString()}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Total=">
        <s:TextInput id="total" prompt="Total"/>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
<s:Button id="check_bn" x="273" y="124" label="Check" click="check_bn_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:Button id="next_bn" x="377" y="123" label="Next" click="next_bn_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:Form id="display_correct" x="649" y="27">
    <s:FormItem label="# Correct">
        <s:Label id="lbl_ratio" text="{n_right}/{n_total} "/>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
<s:Label id="yes_no_lbl" x="462" y="83" width="184" height="61"/>
</s:Application>
```

So how much of this do I put in the component, and how much do I leave in the app? Or is there such a function as a "redraw" that would just run the app again but leave my longer term variables (n_right, etc) alone?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need (at least :) two things:

1) When you generate your next problem, you need to generate two new random numbers (as Sam has just pointed out)

2) Make the variables that hold your random numbers [Bindable]. Otherwise, your text boxes will not be refreshed with their new values. (Just write `[Bindable]` before each `var` in their declaration)

```
[Bindable] public var n_1:Number = Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
[Bindable] public var n_2:Number = Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
```

Comment: Ummmm... Ok, you're right I need to do this, but can't figure out the syntax. In the declaration of, for example: `public var ttl:Number` where do I add the `[Bindable]` to? I've tried a number of places and it always gives me errs. Thanks!

Comment: That seems to work only if I put a ';' at the end of each var declaration line. But thanks!

Comment: Ok... so this one only does math. Can I create components of each (+, -, *, /) and then call on the component? What's the syntax for calling up the component to run? (I know... that's a different question) :)

Comment: I will upvote Sam's answer. We both sort of gave the same answer at the same time.

Comment: yes, better log a different question for that. if you want to be friendly with your kids, be mindful when you make random division problems for them :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like all you want to do is generate a new random question?

```
protected function next_bn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (yes_no_lbl.text == "YES, click NEXT!")
    {
        // reset variables
        n_1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        n_2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

        total.text = "";
        yes_no_lbl.text = "";
        n_total++;      
    }
}
```

This generates two new random numbers, clears `yes_no_lbl`, clears `total`, and increments `n_total`. I added in a logical check, ensuring that the question was answered correct before it makes a new question.

You should also make your `n_1`/`n_2` variables `[Bindable]`, as this will make sure the labels update to display the new value when it changes.

Comment: I like what you did there, but it still gives me the same numbers. Looking at answer below to help solve that. Thanks... as this is a pretty simple solution! (One I can wrap my noob head around.)